# Convert XML to json from Groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to code xml to json using groovy..i have the following code..but from the output {"note":[{"to":["Tove"]},{"from":["Jani"]},{"heading":["Reminder"]}]} i want to remove "[]" things from the output and how can i remove those things.. code as follows

```
def xml = '''<root>
        |    <node>Tim</node>
        |    <node>Tom</node>
        |    <node>
        |      <anotherNode>another</anotherNode>
        |    </node>
        |</root>'''.stripMargin()

// Parse it
def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

// Deal with each node:
def handle
handle = { node ->
  if( node instanceof String ) {
      node
  }
  else {
      [ (node.name()): node.collect( handle ) ]
  }
}
// Convert it to a Map containing a List of Maps
def jsonObject = [ (parsed.name()): parsed.collect { node ->
   [ (node.name()): node.collect( handle ) ]
} ]

// And dump it as Json
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder( jsonObject )

// Check it's what we expected
assert json.toString() == '{"root":[{"node":["Tim"]},{"node":["Tom"]},{"node":         [{"anotherNode":["another"]}]}]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to return a single object (if the list is of length 1), or the list (if it contains more than one element):

```
def crush = { list ->
    list?.size() == 1 ? list[ 0 ] : list
}
```

Then wrap both your `collect` calls in a call to this method:

```
  [ (node.name()): crush( node.collect( handle ) ) ]
```

Comment: def jsonObject = [ (parsed.name()): crush(parsed.collect( { node ->
    // [ (node.name()): node.collect( handle ) ]
     [ (node.name()):  crush(node.collect( handle ))  ]
  })) ]

Comment: I changed my code as but it only remove inner "[]"s .But it didn't remove outer"[]" how can i avoid outer "[]"s..??

Comment: i want to avoid of getting "{}" as well

Comment: @user3282910 Which `{}` do you want to get rid of?  Can you post an example output you'd expect?

Comment: {"note":"to":"Tove","from":"Jani","heading":"Reminder"}

Comment: That's not json though.